# Using array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Below code works absolutely fine using JavaScript. I can print cell[5] in other words any specified index value. But I want to print this in a loop but it does not work. Does any one know why it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var grid_arr = new Array();
    var count = 0;
    var cell;
    cell = {
        x1: 10,
        y1: 10
    };
    alert(cell.x1);
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        cell[i] = {
            x1: i * 5,
            y1: i * 2
        };
    }
    alert(cell[5].x1);
});


/* The below for loop does not display any messages: */

for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    alert(cell[j].x1);
}
```

Comment: Prefer an array literal `[]` to `new Array()`

Comment: Where did you put the second for loop? Outside the `$(document).ready`?

Comment: `for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {` why start from 1 ?

Comment: Where are you invoking this loop? If it is outside the ready function, then you simply don't have cells in scope. Other than that, see Array.length and Array.forEach

Comment: @Sacho — The original question had some of the text as a JS comment which wasn't properly indented. Someone edited it to remove the comment markers instead of indenting it. I've just changed that, it seems to make things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running that code throws a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'x1' of undefined`

This means the `cell[j]` part of `cell[j].x1` is `undefined`.

Basically, when running:

```
for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    alert(cell[j].x1);
}
```

`cell[0]` doesn't exist. The reason is that your `for` loops start counting at different numbers.

Either change that second `for` loop to start counting at `1`, or change the first one:

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    cell[i] = {
```

To start counting at 0.

Try to stay consistent in the way you initialize loops. Preferably, always initialize the index as `0`, as most counting is zero-based in JS.

Comment: i think that solves the issues. But does  the code  cell = {
        x1: 10,
        y1: 10
    };  not assign it to cell[0] ?

Comment: @Happy: No, it does not. `cell = { x1: 10, y1: 10 };` just tells JavaScript to assign the object value of `{ x1: 10, y1: 10 };` to `cell`. You'll have `cell.x1 === 10`, then.

Answer (score 0):

`cell` is a variable locally scooped to the anonymous function that you pass to `ready`.

This means you have two problems:

1. The variable is not accessible globally
2. The variable has not been assigned a value until after the ready event fires

Move your final loop inside the anonymous function or move all the code in that function outside it.

---

Your first loop also starts at 1 while your second starts at 0. This means that (once all the above are sorted) you will be attempting to alert `undefined.x1` which will throw an exception.

Either start your loops at the same point, or test to make sure a value is defined before trying to read its properties.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine. Please try this.

```
var grid_arr = new Array(),
    count = 0,
    cell = new Array();
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    cell.push({
        x1: i * 5,
        y1: i * 2
    });
}
for (var j = 0; j < cell.length; j++) {
    console.log(cell[j].x1);
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: If by _"Just fine"_, you mean _"Logs only 90% of the `cell`'s intended contents"_, you're right. (cell only has 9 properties)
The problem in the OP's code is inconsistency in the `for` loops. That problem still exists in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So many errors in so little code. grid_arr, count is unused. You don't need to use jQuery's document ready function for things that doesn't interact with the DOM. In the first for-loop your index starts from 1, then in your second for loop your index starts from zero. This is how you do it;

```
for( var cell = [], i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    cell.push({
        x1: i * 5,
        y1: i * 2
    });
    alert( cell[i-1].x1 );
}
```

Comment: @user3597525, Agree those variables does not make any link to the code  i have posted here but am using them in rest of my code and also using jquery methods. Also the code you have posted does not work.

Comment: Cerbrus, if the first for arr starts from 1, the second one starts from zero, what is 10-1? It does work. Just tested it. prints out 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45